# Abstract CFT. What does Neukirch mean with exponent here?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory, there is the following Proposition:

[image]

If we take $K$ a field with characteristic $5$, $n=4$, and choose $\Delta=K^{\ast\:4}$, wouldn't it imply that the trivial group has exponent $4$?

Does Neukirch mean exponent of a group $G$ simply to be a number which powers give $1$, not necessarily the smallest?

Comment: The exponent of a group is the least common multiple of the orders of the elements of a group, and here the exponent of the extension is the exponent of its Galois group.

Comment: I was using the exact definition you said, but something is weird. I'm picking a $\Delta$ that forces the extension to be trivial. And the Corollary says it is supposed to have exponent $4$, when the group is $\{1\}$.

Comment: Well, I would phrase the statement saying «whose exponent divides $n$» — the meaning of *exponent* is somewhat standard!

Comment: The author likes to follow standard conventions. I think I have never seen an error in this book. I now suspect that I'm wrong about my $\Delta$ forcing the extension to be trivial. I'll think more about it.

Comment: You can find this result in many places — like Lang's Algebra, under the name of Kummer Theory.

Comment: In particular, your example is correct: if you add the fourth roots of fourth powers (in the presence of fourth roots of unity) you obviously get the trivial extension!

Comment: So, putting an end to it: what he probably means then, is that if we take $\Delta$ as $K^{\ast}$ we get an abelian extension $L/K$ with exponent $n$, and the other subgroups $\Delta$ will correspond to abelian extensions whose exponent divide $n$, right?